# Getting year month day and age between Date and date now using PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the code as below:

```
<tr>
  <td>Date :</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtdembauche" value="<?php echo $value['dateEmbouche'] ?>"class="validate[required] text-input datepicker TextInput"  id="txtdembauche"/></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<?php                           

  @$date1 = $_POST['txtdembauche'];
  $date2 = date("Y-m-d");
  $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
  $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
  $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
  $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));     

?>
<tr>
  <td>Ancienneté : <b id="anciente" style="color:#FF0000;"><?php printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n <br />", $years, $months, $days); ?></b></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<input type="text" name="dateResult" id="dateResult" value="<?php // I do not know how to calculate this ?>">
```

**Problem:**

```
<tr>
  <td>Ancienneté : <b id="anciente" style="color:#FF0000;"><?php printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n <br />", $years, $months, $days); ?></b></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

It not works well,it display the wrong date.

```
<input type="text" name="dateResult" id="dateResult" value="<?php // I do not know how to calculate this ?>">
```

I want to get the age of person between date and date now ex: `12years`, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: not clear what you want to know please describe further what you really need to do.? Do you want to get the difference of the two days or what?

Comment: 2 points that I want to get:
  1.I want to subtract `Date<input type="text" name="txtdembauche" value="<?php echo $value['dateEmbouche'] ?>"class="validate[required] text-input datepicker TextInput"  id="txtdembauche"/>` with the date now to get the result ex:`2 years 3 months 1 day`
 2.I want to get age between `Date<input type="text" name="txtdembauche" value="<?php echo $value['dateEmbouche'] ?>"class="validate[required] text-input datepicker TextInput"  id="txtdembauche"/>` with date now to get result ex: `22years`.

Comment: just echo $date1 and see which format did the date returned from $_POST[txtdembauche]

Comment: Hmm your code seems okay. for your 1st point just `printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);` and for 2nd point `echo $years;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for comments this is something about your coding technique or the concept. I have created a test code just follow it and identify where you went wrong

```
<?php                           
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  @$date1 = $_POST['txtdembauche'];// if format mm/dd/yyyy
  $date2 = date("m/d/Y");//change m,d,y according to input data format
  $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
  $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
  $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
  $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));     
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Date :</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="txtdembauche" value="<?php echo $value['dateEmbouche'] ?>"class="validate[required] text-input datepicker TextInput"  id="txtdembauche"/></td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Age"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ancienneté : </td>
   <td><b id="anciente" style="color:#FF0000;"><?php printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n <br />", $years, $months, $days); ?></b></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Age</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="dateResult" id="dateResult" value="<?php echo $years; ?>"></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes I see but the problem is it display wrong year and wrong result.

Comment: it works perfect for me.give me the date you checked and the answer you got

Comment: I have date `11/02/2010` and I got the result 42.I do not know about this too.

Comment: I think, it error in this part `@$date1 = "$_POST['txtdembauche'];` it can not get the value from it but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: This should be a problem with the matching date formats.Go to basics and just echo $date1 and $data2 and see that the formats are equal or not. if `11/02/2010->>mm/dd/yyyy` then change your date function as `date("m/d/Y");` or if `11/02/2010->>dd/mm/yyyy` change your date function as `date("d/m/Y");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18612/discussion-between-vinu-and-pov-nu)

Comment: Ok thanks you so much @vinu now it works well by changing `$date1 = $value['dateEmbouche']`. Thanks you!:)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$birthday = "1987-01-01";
$timestamp = strtotime($birthday);
$age = (date("md") >= date("md", $timestamp)) ? (date("Y") - date("Y", $timestamp)) : (date("Y") - date("Y", $timestamp) - 1);
echo $age."\n";
```

Hope this can help you!